# The differences between "dainty, small and delicate"

Tags: word-usage

> **Dainty** and **small** girls would love to be pale and **delicate.**

This sentence is from an article about "Looking Good".

When I look over **dainty** on online dictionary
I find its synonyms are "small, delicate". I found other usages such as dainty small earrings, a dainty small cake.

I want to know  "Why did the author use these synonyms together in a sentence?" Is it redundant adjective or emphasis adjective used instead of 'very'.

Comment: You should ask the author.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit redundant.  Remember, anyone can write "good" English but still be a bad *writer*.

Comment: It is not really redundant. You can be dainty and tall, too. Dainty is delicate but it is not small necessarily. Also, dainty can apply to behavior. She ate her food daintily. Dainty applies to the way one holds oneself etc. It is not a term to describe SIZE. In fact, a large man can walk through a minefield in a dainty way.  :)

Answer (score 1):

- **small** is an adjective used to describe *size*
- **delicate** is an adjective used to describe how *fragile* something is
- **dainty** is a form of "delicate" with a meaning of "pretty" and "cute"

For example, lace can be described as "dainty"

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [oldandsold.com](http://www.oldandsold.com/a1photos/lace-curtain.jpg))</sub>


"To walk daintily" could mean "to walk carefully or gingerly" so as not to upset anything under foot (like a cat might do) or "to walk in a *(certain)* stylized feminine manner" (like how a bride might walk in a dress with a long train).